# Module installed but not found when import

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, python-module

I've got a documentation of the package named 'Google-Images-Search'

https://pypi.org/project/Google-Images-Search/

I've read and tyr to reproduce what's needed, so I installed it with this commandline :

```
pip install Google-Images-Search
```

Now when I'm trying to do it again, I've got the message like "Requirement already satisfying" for all dependencies and nothing append after.

So I've develop the file index.py with this inside

```
from google_images_search import GoogleImagesSearch

gis = GoogleImagesSearch('test1', 'test2')
```

But when I execute this, I've got

**No module named Google_Images_Search**

I already try to put in my code

```
help("modules")
```

But Google_Images_Search is not here at all

That more than 2 hours I'm on it, I've try to uninstall pip, pip3, use pip or pip3, reinstall, use python -m pip install ... But nothing work...

Please I don't understand, and I'm beginner with Python and a little with Raspberry and the Linux environment.

Comment: Typo: change `from Google_Images_Search import GoogleImagesSearch` to `from google_images_search import GoogleImagesSearch`. You must read the docs, the package name does not necessarily match the way you import

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry I've put the last try I've done, but yeah the first one was without caps, and still not work

Comment: pip points to python2 in rpi, you must use pip3: `pip3 install Google-Images-Search`

Comment: When I use pip3, I've got the same message telling me that requirement already satisfied

Comment: what is the output of `pip3 list`?

Comment: A long list which contains 
Google-Images-Search 0.3.7

Comment: check the version of python pip install module for: `pip --version`. Then try to strictly specify python version, for example: `python3.6 test.py`. If you have Conda installed, your default python will be that.

Comment: @Masoud Thanks ! That's solve the problem ! I just had to launch the program with python3.5 index.py !

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://pypi.org/project/Google-Images-Search/) states that the name of the module that the project installs is `google_images_search`, all lowercase, not `Google_Images_Search`.

Comment: Same problem without caps

Answer (score 0):

try changing your import,

```
from google_images_search import GoogleImagesSearch
```

Comment: Same problem without caps